# ESLint error: 'default' is restricted from being used as an exported name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am getting this eslint error in index.js file:

> 'default' is restricted from being used as an exported name  no-restricted-exports

**page / index.js**

```
export { default } from './test';
```

**page / test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  return <div>Test</div>;
};
export default Test;
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const testPage = React.lazy(() => import('./page'));

function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={testPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
export default Routes;
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the proper way to resolve it, without disabling that?

Answer (score 4):

```js
export { default as Test } from './test';
```

if above one is used then you've to do named import instead of default import like this

```js
import { Test } from './pathToTestFolder'
```

this is not wrong, but to still using the default import you've to export `test` by default. You can do this

`page/index.js`

```js
import Test from './test'

export default Test
```

now you can use default import like this
`routes.js`

```js
import Test from './pathToTestFolder'
```

or according to your route file

```js
const testPage = React.lazy(() => import('./page'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot export `default` because it's a reserved keyword.
You could replace the line with :

```
export { default as Test } from './test';
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations where `named` and `default` export is conflicting with ESLint rules, you can use `*` export approach as follows:

```
export * from './test';
```